# How can I make the logo pill exceed the div boundary?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So, I've been trying to make the .logo exceed the boundary of the main-nav but I cannot make it do so. I know there's something wrong with how I code but cannot point a finger at it. Help me please?

HTML

```
<div id="landing">
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="./img/logo_final-final.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="nav-btns btns-container">
            <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Store</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Offers</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">FAQs</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2">
        <div class="search-bar">SearchBar</div>
        <div class="profile-info">
            <div class="profile-pic">profile pic</div>
            <div class="profile-name">Name</div>
            <div class="profile-orders">My orders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart">cart</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div> 
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


a{
  text-decoration: none;
}   
#main-nav{
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  top: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  background: #007FFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px #00000029;
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main-nav{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: -5px;
}

#main-nav .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  clear: both;
}

#main-nav .logo{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transform: scale(1.04);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 2px -2px rgb(0, 97, 194);

}

#main-nav .container .logo a{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

#main-nav .container .logo img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#main-nav .container .btns-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#main-nav .container .btns-container div{
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  height: 100%;
}

#main-nav .container-2{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  right:0;
}

#main-nav .container-2 .search-bar{
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
}

#main-nav .container-2 .profile-info{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  'pic pic name name name'
  'pic pic order order order';
  padding: 0rem 3rem;
}
#main-nav .container-2 .profile-info .profile-pic{grid-area:pic;}
#main-nav .container-2 .profile-info .profile-name{grid-area:name;}
#main-nav .container-2 .profile-info .profile-order{grid-area:order;}

#main-nav .container-2 .cart{
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
}
```

I'm sorry if this very confusing. I just got back to HTML/CSS and I forgot how to write code efficiently. Most of the time I just add tags to fix whatever is wrong and don't look into what's causing the problem.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

try this remove `overflow` element from `#main-nav` and the global style `*`
and make the logo `position: absolute;` like this:

```
#main-nav .logo{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transform: scale(1.04);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 2px -2px rgb(0, 97, 194);
  position: absolute;
}

#main-nav{
  /*overflow: hidden;*/ /*remove this*/
  padding: -5px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/ /*remove this*/
}
```

in the last, this is the result:
[image]

so,if you want something else please explain more to help you ,hope my answer is helpful to you

Comment: Will it create any trouble in terms of making the website responsive?

Comment: No, you can use `@media` to make it responsive with any screen -- your ref in this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp